# Problema al añadir datos de un objeo a otro mediante ArrayList

Tags: java

Tengo una clase Main2.java de la siguiente manera simplificada:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

     // Making the instance of Factory:
     Factory myF = new Factory();

     Closet fCloset1 = new Closet("C01",mWood,cBlack,300,200,60);
     Door fpDoor1 = new Door("D01",mWood,cBlack,150,200);
     fCloset1.add(fpDoor1);
     myF.add(fCloset1);
     System.out.println(myF.listOfFurniture());
     }
```

Pues bien el problema que tengo es que cuando añado al objeto fCloset1 los datos de fpDoor1 no me lo añade y por tanto cuando imprimo la lista solo me aparecen los datos de fCloset1 y no todo junto.

La clase Closet está realizada de la siguiente manera:

```
       public class Closet extends Furniture{

   // The new line separator:
   private final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   /**
   * This atribute stores the Furniture width
   */
   private double width;
   /**
    * This atribute stores the Furniture height
    */
   private double height;
   /**
    * This atribute stores the Furniture depth
    */
   private double depth;

   /**
    * This atribute stores the list of frontparts
    */
   private ArrayList<FrontPart> frontparts;

   /**
    * Constructor method
    *
    * @param id
    *            the Furniture id
    * @param material
    *            the Furniture material object
    * @param w
    *            the Closet width
    * @param h
    *            the Closet height
    * @param d
    *            the Closet depth
    */
   public Closet(String id, Material material, Color color, double w,       double h, double d) {
      // TODO
      super(id,material,color);
      this.width = w;
      this.height = h;
      this.depth = d;
      this.frontparts=new ArrayList<FrontPart>();
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute width
    * @return atribute width
    */
   public double getWidth() {
      return this.width;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute height
    * @return atribute height
    */
   public double getHeight() {
      return this.height;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute depth
    * @return atribute depth
   */
   public double getDepth() {
  return this.depth;
  }

   /**
    * Add a FrontPart to this object
    * @param f FrontPart object
    */
   public void add(FrontPart f) {
     // TODO
     this.frontparts.add(f);
   }

   /**
    * This method generates and returns the information of
    * every element in the front parts list of the closet, in
    * the order they were introduced.
     * @return 
    */
   public String listOfFrontParts() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     for (Iterator<FrontPart> it = frontparts.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        FrontPart  f = (FrontPart) it.next();
         sb.append(f.toString());
      }
      return sb.toString();
   } 



   /**
    * This method calculates and returns the price of the
    * Furniture.
    *
    * The price of the Furniture is calculated as:
     *   (sum of its areas) x (price per cm2 of the material) x (price factor of the color)
    *
    * @return price of the Furniture
    */
       public double price() {
      // TODO
     // return 0.0;
      double area;
      area =  height*depth*2 +width*height;
      return (area * this.getMaterial().getPricePerCm2()*this.getColor   ().getPriceFactor()+this.frontPartsPrice());
   }


   /**
    * This method generates and returns an String with
    * the information of the Furniture object.
    *
    * Note that this method has to access to the Material
    * and Color atributes of the class to get some information,
    * and that this method also gets price from front parts, if any,
    * to add to final price.
    */
   public String toString() {
      // TODO
     // return null;
 DecimalFormat myFormat1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
      DecimalFormat myFormat2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(super.toString());
      sb.append("  Closet made on " + this.getMaterial().getName() + "with color "+ this.getColor().getName()+ NL);
      sb.append("  Material price: " + myFormat1.format(this.getMaterial().getPricePerCm2()) + " euros per cm2" + NL);
      sb.append("  Width: " + myFormat2.format(this.width) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Height: " + myFormat2.format(this.height) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Depth: " + myFormat2.format(this.depth) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Color price factor: " + myFormat2.format(this.getColor().getPriceFactor()) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Body Price: " + myFormat2.format(this.price()) + " euros" + NL);
    return sb.toString();
   }
```

Esta clase esta unida a la clase FrontPart que es abstracta y super clase de Door

La clase frontpart

```
public abstract class FrontPart {

   /**
    * The new line separator
    */
   private String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   /**
    * This atribute stores the product identification code
    */
   private String id;

   /**
    * This atribute stores the product material object
    */
   private Material material;
   private Color color;

   /**
    * Constructor method
    *
    * @param id
    *            the FrontPart id
    * @param material
    *            the FrontPart material object
    * @param color
    *            the FrontPart color object
    */
   public FrontPart(String id, Material material, Color color) {
     this.id = id;
     this.material = material;
     this.color = color;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute id
    * @return atribute id
    */
   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute material
    * @return atribute material
    */
   public Material getMaterial() {
      return this.material;
   }

   /**
     * Getter method of atribute color
     * @return atribute color
     */
    public Color getColor() {
      return this.color;
   }

   /**
    * Abstract method price (developed in every subclass)
    */
   abstract double price();

   /**
    * This method generates and returns an String with
    * the product identification code.
    */
   public String toString() {
      return "  FrontPart id: " + this.id + NL;
   }
}
```

Por ultimo la clase Door

```
public class Door extends FrontPart{

   // The new line separator:
   private final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   /**
    * This atribute stores the bed X dimension
    */
   private double x;

   /**
    * This atribute stores the bed Y dimension
    */
   private double y;

   /**
    * Constructor method
    *
    * @param id
    *            the FrontPart id
    * @param material
    *            the FrontPart material object
    * @param color
    *            the FrontPart color object
    * @param x
    *            the door x dimension
    * @param y
    *            the door y dimension
    */
   public Door(String id, Material material, Color color, double x, double y) {
      // TODO
      super(id,material,color);
      this.x=x;
      this.y=y;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute x
    * @return atribute x
    */
   public double getX() {
      return this.x;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute y
    * @return atribute y
    */
   public double getY() {
      return this.y;
   }

   /**
    * This method calculates and returns the price of the
    * Bed.
    *
    * The price of the Bed is calculated as:
    *   (its Area) x (price per cm2 of the material) x (price factor of the color)
    *
    * @return price of the cylinder
     */
   public double price() {
      // TODO
  //    return 0.0;
    double area;
    area= x*y;
    return (area*this.getMaterial().getPricePerCm2()*this.getColor().getPriceFactor());
   }

   /**
    * This method generates and returns an String with
    * the information of the Door object.
    *
    * Note that this method has to access to the Material
    * and Color atributes of the class to get some information.
    */
   public String toString() {
     DecimalFormat myFormat1 = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");
      DecimalFormat myFormat2 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(super.toString());
      sb.append("  Door made on " + this.getMaterial().getName() + "with color "+ this.getColor().getName()+ NL);
      sb.append("  Material price: " + myFormat1.format(this.getMaterial().getPricePerCm2()) + " euros per cm2" + NL);
      sb.append("  X " + myFormat2.format(this.x) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Y " + myFormat2.format(this.y) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("  Color price factor: " + myFormat2.format(this.getColor().getPriceFactor()) + " cm" + NL);
      sb.append("Front part Price " + myFormat2.format(this.price()) + " euros" + NL);
    return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme y que me explicase de una manera correcta.

Te pongo el código de la clave Furniture para ver si veis algo:

```
     public abstract class Furniture{
  /**
   * The new line separator
    */ 
   private String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");

   /**
    * This atribute stores the product identification code
    */
   private String id;

   /**
    * This atribute stores the product material object
    */
   private Material material;
   private Color color;

   /**
    * Constructor method
    *
    * @param id
    *            the Furniture id
    * @param material
    *            the Furniture material object
    * @param color
    *            the Furniture color object
    */
   public Furniture(String id, Material material, Color color) {
      this.id = id;
      this.material = material;
      this.color = color;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute id
    * @return atribute id
    */
   public String getId() {
      return this.id;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute material
    * @return atribute material
    */
   public Material getMaterial() {
      return this.material;
   }

   /**
    * Getter method of atribute color
    * @return atribute color
    */
   public Color getColor() {
     return this.color;
   }

   /**
    * Abstract method price (developed in every subclass)
    */
   abstract double price();

    /**
    * This method generates and returns an String with
    * the product identification code.
    */
   public String toString() {
      return "Furniture id: " + this.id + NL;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hace falta saber el código de `myF.listOfFurniture()` porque si no no sabemos qué te tiene que imprimir. No obstante veo que en el método 'toString()` de `Closet` nunca llamas al método `listOfFrontParts()` que entiendo que será el encargado de eso, por eso tamibén hará falta el código del método `toString()` de `Furniture` que sí podría llamarlo y ya lo estés haciendo en la línea `sb.append(super.toString());` de `Closet.toString()`

Comment: Te pongo el código de la clave Furniture para ver si veis algo @Awes0meM4n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que nunca añades a tu método `Closet.toString()` la lista de `FrontParts` que tienes cargada. Añade al final de ese método esta línea:

```
sb.append(listOfFrontParts());
```

Antes de `return sb.toString();`

Comment: Efectivamente, estaba obcecado, tienes razón, ese era el problema.Perfecto!